# How can I position a button distant to the corner?

Tags: css

I want to position a button a little bit distant to right corner like this:

[image: Example]

How can I do this ?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking

Comment: You still have to add the context of the button, where is the Mentorship text, or that's just an example?

Comment: @MihailMinkov Just an example. I just want a button a little bit distant to corner

Comment: I'm sorry, i couldn't help. In this case the answer of Mihail Minkov should be your solution. Make sure, to thank him for his time and efford.

Comment: Thanks @e-r-a :) .

Comment: @UmutArpat I added some extra info in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in many ways, but it depends a lot on your existing code.

One option could be:

```css
button#hello { /* assuming id */
    float: right;
}
```

Another option could be:

```css
#button-container { /* also assuming id */ 
    text-align: right;
}
```

And also if you use flex, you could use:

```
#button-container { /* assuming id again */
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

It would be a lot easier if you share some of your code structure.

**EDIT**

If you want to separate the button slightly from your container, you could add `margin-right: 20px` or something similar. It would help a lot if you add a visual example of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make container as flexbox as below.

### CSS:

```
.buttonbar {
    display         : flex;
    flex-direction  : row;
    justify-content : center;
    align-items     : center;
}
```

### JSX:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div class="buttonbar">
          <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">Merhaban</Button>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Ya Ramadhan</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your post.But this is not what I want.It gives me two buttons but it is too close to the corner.How can I make it a little distant to the corner ?

Comment: @UmurArpat, it would help if you show where your corner is and how distant you want it from there.

Comment: Which corner? is that <div class="buttonbar"> contained in another div?